# How can I handle configuration files in Perl?

Tags: perl, configuration-files

I'm refactoring an old script that does some operations on different sites. It needs to use a configuration file which is now a manually parsed text file with this format:

```
label:domain:username:password:path
```

Of course the number of lines is potentially unlimited.

I know there are a few modules which deal with config files. Which one is the best for this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking to **change** the format, please look at the recommendations here:

[How do you manage configuration files in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746972/how-do-you-manage-configuration-files-in-perl)

If you're looking to parse the **existing** format, that format looks to be more of a comma-separated file than a "configuration" file, so I'd say go with Text::CSV (it allows you to choose a separator character in a constructor, so you can do colon-separated instead of comma-separated), or for very large files Text::CSV_XS.

```
use Text::CSV; # Example adapted from POD

my @rows;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { sep_char => ":" } )  
             or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();

open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", "test.conf" or die "test.conf: $!";
while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {
    push @rows, $row; # $row is arrayref containing your fields
}
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
close $fh;
```

Comment: Look at `Text::xSV` too -- I happen to think its interface is a lot more sensible than Text::CSV's.