# Why is it a bad idea to write configuration data in code?

Tags: perl, language-agnostic

Real-life case (from [caff](http://pgp-tools.alioth.debian.org/)) to exemplify the short question subject:

```
$CONFIG{'owner'} = q{Peter Palfrader};
$CONFIG{'email'} = q{peter@palfrader.org};
$CONFIG{'keyid'} = [ qw{DE7AAF6E94C09C7F 62AF4031C82E0039} ];
$CONFIG{'keyserver'} = 'wwwkeys.de.pgp.net';
$CONFIG{'mailer-send'} = [ 'testfile' ];
```

Then in the code: `` eval `cat $config` ``, access `%CONFIG`

---

Provide answers that lay out the general problems, not only specific to the example.

Comment: Tagged *language-agnostic* because this is possible in dynamic languages, and in principle in all. Tagged *Perl* specifically because it gladly gives you enough proverbial rope, writing this sort of scheme above is very easy. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746972/how-do-you-manage-configuration-files-in-perl

Comment: You could follow how JSON came about. Someone notices that you can deliver data into a Javascript environment by exactly this technique, run code that evaluates to the object containing the data. They immediately realize that this is way too permissive, so they specify a "safe" subset of Javascript so that you can use a familiar syntax, with results exactly the same as if you had run equivalent Javascript, but without the opportunity to mix code in with your data, and hence the result is easier to reason about (has no side effects, etc).

Comment: At my site we have adopted a tool called Chef for deployments - its config files, called "recipes", have elaborate syntax that is practically a language in its own right

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are many reasons to avoid configuration in code, and I go through some of them in the configuration chapter in [Mastering Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527242).

- No configuration change should carry the risk of breaking the program. It certainly shouldn't carry the risk of breaking the compilation stage.
- People shouldn't have to edit the source to get a different configuration.
- People should be able to share the same application without using a common group of settings, instead re-installing the application just to change the configuration.
- People should be allowed to create several different configurations and run them in batches without having to edit the source.
- You should be able to test your application under different settings without changing the code.
- People shouldn't have to learn how to program to be able to use your tool.
- You should only loosely tie your configuration data structures to the source of the information to make later architectural changes easier.
- You really want an interface instead of direct access at the application level.

I sum this up in my *Mastering Perl* class by telling people that the first rule of programming is to create a situation where you do less work and people leave you alone. When you put configuration in code, you spend more time dealing with installation issues and responding to breakages. Unless you like that sort of thing, give people a way to change the settings without causing you more work.

Comment: "People should have to learn how to program to be able to use your tool." =~ s/should/shouldn't/

Comment: I don't agree with almost all of these *You should* or *People should* listed here.

Comment: Many programmers don't agree, which is why most non-programmers hate having to talk to programmers about anything.

Comment: one weak pro for inline configuration is allowing a portable single file solution.  Use sane defaults and allow them to be overridden in a config file and/or cmdline and that pro is moot.

Comment: You can still have a non-code configuration string that acts as the default file. Still, as you say, you need defaults anyway.

Comment: Hrm. I agree with most of your points, but I feel like there's two things being squeezed together that aren't necessarily the same. I do agree that config data should be external to a program (separate file, never inline), which your points address. But I also think it's possible to use (simple) code as your config file format. For some config requirements, that may be the cleanest and best way to handle it. Some apps/tools require quite complex configurations, and I've seen some where the config was a huge pain to work with because they tried to cram it into a simple "key=value" style.

Comment: You don't have to use key=value configurations if you use non-code. There are plenty of text formats that can be quite complex and still not be code. It's not that I'm trying to squeeze those together; that's what the question is.

Answer (score 12):

```
$CONFIG{'unhappy_employee'} = `rm -rf /`
```

Comment: Your review process is pretty *broken* if that could make it into production! And how would that not be caught in QA?

Comment: @Axeman: Indeed, some shops DO have pretty bad processes. And if this is an internal maintenance tool only used by a handful of people, the chances of a rigorous review are even slimmer and the opportunity for this sort of thing increases. One person simply appends one line to the config file on the server, the scheduled job runs at the appointed time, and then, BAM!!

Comment: If the review process is bad, it is bad. I would simply have to add the same thing to code that wasn't reviewed. Or `system( $path_to_utility_in_config )`

Comment: @Axeman: With a simple text-file for configuration, this wouldn't even be an issue.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: sure it is, because you could still obfuscate it with config properties like `path_to_browser=/bin/rm\n browser_flags=-rf\n default_url=/` and put `system( $konqueror_path, $browser_flags, $uninit_url || $default_url )` or something more tricky. A hole in the review process is a hole in the review process.

Comment: @Axeman: Ok, that example would work, though it assumes that at least one of the config option values will be taken as a program name and executed. In the OP's example config file (which doesn't seem to be executing any of the config values as programs), malicious code doesn't even have to begin with `$CONFIG{'key'} = ...`, they could put ANYthing into the file to have it executed.

Answer (score 12):

One major issue with this approach is that your config is not very portable. If a functionally identical tool were built in Java, loading configuration would have to be redone. If both the Perl and the Java variation used a simple `key=value` layout such as:

```
owner = "Peter Palfrader"
email = "peter@peter@palfrader.org"
...
```

they could share the config.

Also, calling `eval` on the config file seems to open this system up to attack. What could a malicious person add to this config file if they wanted to wreak some havoc? Do you realize that ANY arbitrary code in your config file *will* be executed?

Another issue is that it's highly counter-intuitive (at least to me). I would expect a config file to be read by some config loader, not executed as a runnable piece of code. This isn't so serious but could confuse new developers who aren't used to it.

Finally, while it's *highly unlikely* that the implementation of constructs like `p{...}` will ever change, if they *did* change, this might fail to continue to function.

Comment: The thing is, tho', that that is valid syntax in many languages. In that case the config would be loaded by "source"ing the file.

Comment: @Gaius: It may be valid syntax but that certainly doesn't mean it will be `eval`'d to load it. A .properties file in Java is of the form `key=value` but it is not executed as if it were code. If I were doing this in Perl, I'd attempt a similar approach of parsing the file line by line and storing the data in some structure, and not simply executing it as if it were code.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bad idea to put configuration data in *compiled* code, because it can't be easily changed by the user. For scripts, just make sure it's separated entirely from the rest and document it nicely.

Comment: It's also a bad idea to change configuration without at least an abbreviated life cycle.

Comment: If you're going to deploy a script on multiple machines then you don't want to have to edit it on each host as you install it.  Better to separate the concerns and have the logic in a script and the config in a config file.

Answer (score 6):

A reason I'm surprised no one mentioned yet is **testing**. When config is in the code you have to write crazy, contorted tests to be able to test safely. You can end up writing tests that duplicate the code they test which makes the tests nearly useless; mostly just testing themselves, likely to drift, and difficult to maintain.

Hand in hand with testing is deployment which was mentioned. When something is easy to test, it is going to be easy (well, easier) to deploy.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue here is reusability in an environment where multiple languages are possible. If your config file is in language A, then you want to share this configuration with language B, you will have to do some rewriting.

This is even more complicated if you have more complex configurations (example the apache config files) and are trying to figure out how to handle potential differences in data structures. If you use something like JSON, YAML, etc., parsers in the language will be aware of how to map things with regards to the data structures of the language.

The one major drawback of not having them in a language, is that you lose the potential of utilizing setting config values to dynamic data.

Answer (score 1):

Reason 1. Aesthetics. While no one gets harmed by *bad smell*, people tend to put effort into getting rid of it.

Reason 2. Operational cost. For a team of 5 this is probably ok, but once you have developer/sysadmin separation, you must hire sysadmins who understand Perl (which is $$$), or give developers access to production system (big $$$).

And to make matters worse you won't have time (also $$$) to introduce a configuration engine when you *suddenly* need it.

Comment: R1 is not an explanation. *Why/for what reason* do people consider this a smell/unaesthetic?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Tim Anderson. Somebody here confuses configuration in code as configuration not being configurable. This is corrected for compiled code.

Both a perl or ruby file is read and interpreted, as is a yml file or xml file with configuration data. I choose yml because it is easier on the eye than in code, as grouping by test environment, development, staging and production, which in code would involve more .. code.

As a side note, XML contradicts the "easy on the eye" completely. I find it interesting that XML config is extensively used with compiled languages.

Answer (score 0):

My main problem with configuration in many small scripts I write, is that they often contain login data (username and password or auth-token) to a service I use. Then later, when the scripts gets bigger, I start versioning it and want to upload it on github.

So before every commit I need to replace my configuration with some dummy values.

```
$CONFIG{'user'} = 'username';
$CONFIG{'password'} = '123456';
```

Also you have to be careful, that those values did not eventually slip into your commit history at some point. This can get very annoying. When you went through this one or two times, you will never again try to put configuration into code.