# How to read my own configuration file in perl

Tags: perl

How do I read my own configuration file with .pl extension? I have used require to read that file in my script. But I am not sure is this the right way to do it? Can you please suggest me how to do this?

And also when I read the config file with require in my script, I get the errors like Global symbol requires explicit package name. How to solve this?

Here is the example:

This is my config file:

```
$USERNAME="sach";
$PASSWORD="sach123";
$DBNAME="personal";
$HOST="localhost";
$LIST_OLD_FILES_FILE="old_files.txt";
$remove_files=1;
$File_path="/sach/";
```

And here is how I call it in my script:

```
require "config.pl" ;
$dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$DBNAME:$HOST",$USERNAME,$PASSWORD) or 
     die "$dbh->errstr\n";
```

Comment: I think you need to show examples of the config file and how you are calling it.

Comment: Don't use raw Perl as a config file. Use a proper config format and something like [Config::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/Config::Tiny)

Comment: @Quentin: you should've answered instead of commenting.

Comment: sach, [Why is it a bad idea to write configuration data in code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969417/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-write-configuration-data-in-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) command to read in a configuration file with perl code in it.

```
do 'config.pl';
```

Comment: Thanks Brant. But what is the difference between do and require? They are almost identical.

Comment: @sach `require` is for modules, adds an entry to `%INC`, and prevents double-loading. `do` is lower-level. read `perldoc -f require` and `perldoc -f do`.

Comment: @Brant : Changed back ticks to single quotes