# How to read and update a pm file line by line?

Tags: perl

In a Perl script, we are retrieving configuration details from a pm file. After the user changes the configuration details using the script's interface, the same values should be written back in the pm file.

For example, I have the following `config.pm` file:

```
$SourcePrimUserHost = '10.226.33.233';
$SourcePrimUserPort = '33002';
$SourceGroupsHost = '10.226.33.233';
$SourceGroupsPort = '33002';
```

I'm reading these values from a Perl script. I want to store updated values back to `config.pm` file.

How can we do this? Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Can you provide some more information?

Comment: I have a config.pm file with values say,

$SourcePrimUserHost = '10.226.33.233';
$SourcePrimUserPort = '33002';
$SourceGroupsHost = '10.226.33.233';
$SourceGroupsPort = '33002';

Im reading this values from a perl script and displaying this on command promot(user can change this values). I want to store the update values back to config.pm file. How can i do this?

Comment: Now you know why a Perl program is not a good storage format. You should be asking what is.

Comment: Related: [Why is it a bad idea to write configuration data in code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969417/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-write-configuration-data-in-code)

Answer (score 12):

This is *not* a good design choice.

1. The Perl module may (should!) be installed in such a way that the user can read, but not write it.
2. If the module is used by multiple users or multiple Perl programs, then the conf would be system-global and not application-specific.
3. Issues arise if multiple instances of the program are run at the same time.

I would recommend using a data serialization format like YAML, although JSON, Freeze/Thaw and Dumper may be other contestants. This configuration would best be stored in a seperate file.

If you *have* to store the data in the same file, you could use the `__DATA__` token. Everything behind that is accessible inside the code as the `DATA` filehandle, and will not be executed by perl. It is also trivial to find this token when updating the configuration. If the module is called `Foo::Bar`:

```
my $serialized_stuff = ...;
my $self_loc = $INC{"Foo/Bar.pm"}; # %INC holds the location for every loaded module.
my $tempfile = ...;
open $SELF, "<", $self_loc or die ...;
open $TEMP, ">", $tempfile or die ...;
# don't touch anything before __DATA__
while(<$SELF>) {
  print $TEMP $_;
  last if /^__DATA__$/;
}
print $TEMP $serialized_stuff;
close $TEMP; close $SELF;
rename $tempfile => $self_loc or die ...;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use one of the many configuration tools like [Config::General](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Config-General/General.pm) from [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/). They are easy to use, support different notations and you can write back your values into a text file.