# How to read and replace the configuration data in Perl

Tags: perl

Here is the below config.pm file.

```
$AHost = '10.226.33.233';
$APort = '33002';
$ADBUser = "enacct";
$ADBPassword = "enacct";
```

Im reading this file in some.pl file using sysread and it's fetching the entire file data as a string(and after modification we are passing the entire string as a parameter to write. It will write it back to the file).

Suppose i want to replace the value for $AHost with '10.226.33.234' and $ADBUser as "pwd";. How can we do it?

I mean we should replace the corresponding changed values in the string retrieved and by sending this updated string back we can write the data back into file correctly.

How to update the string with this scenario?

Thanks,

Comment: Looks a lot like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806888/how-to-read-and-update-a-pm-file-line-by-line

Comment: You have already been told that this isn't the way to do it. Take a look at the `Config` modules on CPAN.

Answer (score 0):

1: You could use Getopt::Euclid to store the default config values in your script and it will let you tto overwrite any of them from commanline. It is also self documenting.

2: Use YAML to store config data, you could use YAML::Tiny to read it

Example:

```
file.yaml (there should be an empty line at the end of the file!)

    ---
    AHost: blah
    APort: bah



    use YAML::Tiny;

    # Create a YAML file
    my $yaml = YAML::Tiny->new;

    # Open the config
    $yaml = YAML::Tiny->read( 'file.yml' );

    # Reading properties
    my $AHost = $yaml->[0]->{AHost};
```