# perl6 'do(file)' equivalent

Tags: raku

In perl5 I used to 'do (file)' for configuration files like this:

```
---script.pl start ---
our @conf = ();
do '/path/some_conf_file';
...
foreach $item (@conf) {
    $item->{rules} ...
...
---script.pl end ---

---/path/some_conf_file start ---
# arbitrary code to 'fill' @conf
@conf = (
{name => 'gateway',
    rules => [
        {verdict => 'allow', srcnet => 'gw', dstnet => 'lan2'}
    ]
},

{name => 'lan <-> lan2',
    rules => [
        {srcnet => 'lan', dstnet => 'lan2',
         verdict => 'allow', dstip => '192.168.5.0/24'}
    ]
},
);
---/path/some_conf_file end ---
```

Also Larry Wall's "Programming Perl" also mentions this method:

> But do FILE is still useful for such things as reading program
>   configuration files. Manual error checking can be done this way:

```
# read in config files: system first, then user 
for $file ("/usr/share/proggie/defaults.rc",
                "$ENV{HOME}/.someprogrc") {
         unless ($return = do $file) {
             warn "couldn't parse $file: $@" if $@;
             warn "couldn't do $file: $!"    unless defined $return;
             warn "couldn't run $file"       unless $return;
         } }
```

**Benefits**:

- does not require write your own parser each time - perl parse and
  create data structures for you;
- faster/simpler: native perl data
  structures/types without overheads for converting from external format (like YAML);
- does not require manipulate @INC to load the
  module from somewhere compared to module as conf file;
- less extra
  code compared to modules as conf file;
- "syntax" of "configuration file" is powerful as perl itself;
- "ad hoc" format;

**Disadvantages**:

- no isolation: we can execute/destroy anything from "configuration
  file";

How do I get the same with perl6?
Is there way to do it better in perl6 (without **Disadvantages**) and without parsing own syntax, grammars, module including?
Something like "Load hashes or arrays from text representation from file"?

Comment: https://github.com/teodozjan/perl-store ?

Comment: There are more disadvantages/arguments against: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5969417

Comment: `EVALFILE`, cf [5to6-perlfunc](http://doc.perl6.org/language/5to6-perlfunc#do)

Comment: I'd argue that if what you need is "just" to "load hashes or arrays from text", then you'd be better served by JSON or other serialization formats. `do($file)` implies something more than that though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `EVALFILE($file)` (ref. http://doc.perl6.org/language/5to6-perlfunc#do).

As you pointed out, using `EVALFILE` has disadvantages, so I'm not going to add anything in that direction :-)

Here's a sample configuration file:

```
# Sample configuration (my.conf)
{
    colour  => "yellow",
    pid     => $*PID,
    homedir => %*ENV<HOME> ~ "/.myscript",
    data_source => {
        driver => "postgres",
        dbname => "test",
        user   => "test_user",
    }
}
```

and here's a sample script using it:

```
use v6;

# Our configuration is in this file
my $config_file = "my.conf";
my %config := EVALFILE($config_file);

say "Hello, world!\n";

say "My homedir is %config<homedir>";
say "My favourite colour is %config<colour>";
say "My process ID is %config<pid>";
say "My database configuration is:";
say %config<data_source>;

if $*PID != %config<pid> {
    say "Strange. I'm not the same process that evaluated my configuration.";
}
else {
   say "BTW, I am still the same process after reading my own configuration.";
}
```