# compile and execute program written in subset of perl6 with rakudo

Tags: dsl, raku

Suppose I would like to use simple language that is only a **subset** of Perl6 as a extension/embeddable language to "script" my own Perl 6 programs. 
For example let this language has only:

- variable declaration
- expressions
- literals

with Perl6 syntax and may be very limited subset of built in functions.

Anything outside of this should cause a compilation error and should not 
executed.

Is it possible to (re)use Rakudo compiler for this or it can be done only by hand-written interpreter/compiler?

Let me clarify my motivation for this.

1. Using (subset of) host language (Perl 6 in this case) as
   DSL-language for configuration files for scripts/apps written in
   host language.
    This can be done with EVAL
   ([perl6 'do(file)' equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616160/perl6-dofile-equivalent)),
   but it's not safe at all since there is no control what EVAL can do.
2. Using (subset of) host language as extension/scripting language for
   apps written in host language. Much like scripting Blender with
   Python or WoW with Lua. I guess app core with some API is needed in this case? But how exactly it should/can be done?

But again, why host language for configuration/scripting?
In case of conf files I don't like using "foreign languages" like YAML or JSON because:

- extra code/library needed to convert data from those formats into native Perl6 memory data structures, but we already have all (language and compiler) to express conf's contents;
- conf file may use host language code natively (i.e. callbacks) with compile-time checks;
- portability of conf files is not issue in my case;

In case of extension/scripting: again, I don't see any reason to use Lua or Python for Perl 6 apps, but again I don't like idea about inventing my own extension/scripting language and writing interpreter/compiler for it in Perl 6
if I already have Perl 6/Rakudo.

Comment: Wouldn't allowing perl6 expressions be like allowing most of perl6?

Comment: @sftf As I understand things... In theory one could A) inherit from the regular Perl 6 grammar and pare it down and B) create an appropriate custom "setting" to take care of the "limited subset of built in functions" aspect... In practice both A) and B) will likely become ever more pain for ever less gain the more you pare things back: creating and deploying replacements for ever more challenging bootstrapping cheat problems as you go. It definitely depends on your specific goals but I suspect a new lang with a compiler written in Perl 6 to target back to Perl 6 would be a lot easier in 2016.

Comment: @sftf Are you replacing an already written system, playing around with ideas, building a business, ...?

Comment: @raiph I'm "playing around with ideas"...

Comment: @raiph I added some explanation about subj

Answer (score 1):

I know that this isn't the answer you were looking for, but I really think most configuration can be handled well by JSON. JSON is well accepted outside of the JavaScript community. Many languages use it. In fact, [`JSON::Fast`](https://modules.perl6.org/dist/JSON::Fast:cpan:TIMOTIMO) comes with Rakudo-Star (as evidenced by [it's `json_fast` submodule](https://github.com/rakudo/star/tree/master/modules)). You can convert JSON files to Perl 6 data structures with this one-liner (okay, two-liner including `use JSON::Fast`):

```
use JSON::Fast;
my %json = from-json(slurp($filename));
```

Also, JSON is a pretty decent data structure. It can be simple if you need simple, but you can use it for very complex configurations using nested hashes and arrays in just about any combination.

Answer (score 0):

Perl 6 code can be [abstracted into Blocks](https://docs.perl6.org/language/functions). You can declare Block-type variables, and you can also declare subset of blocks using [`where`](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2016/12/08/how-to-make-use-and-abuse-perl-6-subsets/). If you are able to express the restrictions to your Perl 6 blocks into Perl 6 expressions, you can easily create subsets of Perl 6 combining those constraints. Your DSL will then be 
valid objects of the (sub)type you have declared.

Comment: this approach will not guard against unwanted pieces of the language being used, nor against unwanted code being executed (think BEGIN blocks and friends) and it is very unlikely that a Perl 6 expression to define limitations on the code would work at all; there's simply no API for introspecting the code behind a Block object.

Comment: Then the only way would be to re-define Perl 6 using a grammar, I guess...